# cuda Occupancy Max Active Blocks Per Multiprocessor == 0?

Tags: cuda

I have problem with:

```
cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(gpuNo); //GPU select
cudaDeviceProp prop;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, gpuNo);
int ileWatkow = 512;
int ileSM = prop.multiProcessorCount;
int ileBlokow;
cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(&ileBlokow, KernelTransformataPET_optymalizacja2, ileWatkow, 0);
```

in 1080Ti return `ileBlokow=1,` but if I compile and run in 2080Ti return `ileBlokow=0`,

sometimes if I copy paste kernel in new project in 1080Ti will return `ileBlokow=0`. I do not know what is going on...

kernel is a little big... contain a lot of code lines...

```
1>  ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z36KernelTransformataPET_optymalizacja2P6float2S0_S0_PfS1_S1_S1_PiS2_S2_' for 'sm_61'
1>  ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z36KernelTransformataPET_optymalizacja2P6float2S0_S0_PfS1_S1_S1_PiS2_S2_
1>      408 bytes stack frame, 490 bytes spill stores, 904 bytes spill loads
1>  ptxas info    : Used 255 registers, 424 bytes cumulative stack size, 16384 bytes smem, 400 bytes cmem[0]
1>  ptxas info    : Function properties for _ZnwyPv
1>      0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
1>  ptxas info    : Function properties for __brev
1>      0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
```

This is what return the ptxas info.

if I compile with CC 6.1 for 1080 or for 7.5 for 2080 it is no different between it.

there is no different between cuda toolkit 9.1 or 10.1, in both is the same problem

someone can help, give me some tips or advice, where i should looking my problem ?

platform: Windows + VS 2015

Comment: 255 registers per thread * 512 threads per block = 130,560 registers per block. There is no hardware which supports more than 64k registers per block so that answer should be 0 all the time -- this kernel shouldn't and won't run at that block size on any supported GPU

Comment: Ohh... You are right, but there is some possibilities to tell compiler "you should use on 128 register/thread" ?  

I use only:
 25 int variable,
 1 uint variable,
 12 float variable,
 1 bool variable,

 2x table float2 in shared memory. 

Total is 39 variable + two table in Shared Memory. 
Rest registers probably is used for if statements or for one for statements...

Comment: The obvious thing to do is reduce the block size

Comment: Yes, but I must change algorithm - I implement FFT and it is not easy to reimplement it on 256 threads or 128 threads per block... maybe there is other way ?

Comment: if I go this way, it could happen that I decrease threads but I must change algorithm - add some loops, so compiler probably increase usage register? it is possible that compiler must use more than 255register/thread ? I know it is the max limit, but could happened ?

Comment: The compiler will not emit code with illegal resource requirements. It will fail with an error in that case. You can try the `maxregcount` option to reduce the number of registers the compiler targets, but let's face it, the problem is your code, not the compiler. Consider refactoring it

Comment: @PiotrPluta: "maybe there is other way ?" => Do you want to necessarily have your own implementation? If not, [CuFFT](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html) is an obvious option. Also, "25 int variable, 1 uint variable, 12 float variable, ...." => I don't think register usage can be calculated this way.

Comment: As explained [here](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/register_spilling.pdf), if you are using `maxregcount`, consider that local mem will be used if the source code exceeds register limit which in turn may affect performance.

Comment: [cufftDx](https://developer.nvidia.com/cufft) provides for FFT operations that can be directly integrated into device code, without writing your own FFT algorithms.  It's currently in an EA status.  You may want to consider it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I know, but I have implement FFT including some multiply others matrix. It is algorithm for iterative statistical reconstruction image for  CT and PET. 
on 1080Ti for 10 000 iterations (20 000 FFT & 20 000 IFFT in 2D 1024x1024) we have less than 15s, tomorrow I will test on 2080Ti and on Titan V. 

In sometimes I consider this library, but I still do not have time for implement it... :(

Comment: @User81862311, I know I can programming in assembler in CPU and I know that is necessary using some registers for working loop or if-statement. But if you have about 30 variable and now only two nested loop with sometimes one if statement is really hard believe that this compiler required 255 register for working...

probably in future I implement it in PTX for using less registers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

There was a 2 things:

1. I send to kernel information about iteration as INT, but I copied as SHORT
   Here was a big problem for "newest" GPU, the highest bit was random... but for 1080Ti was zero, so works normally.

-> this was my mistake but also I thing problem with cuda copy from host to device method for newest card than 1080ti.

2. I reduce used registers from 255 do 230... and after recompiled it in CudaToolkit 12 - this registers decreased to 83 :) It is amazing for me :)

So, my problem is resolved, thank everyone for help :) Special thank you for @Robert Crovella

Comment: Please accept your answer so that this question is marked as answered